# PDF2pic: Error: write EPIPE error on converting pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert a pdf document in to images (each page as separate image).
I am using the package pdf2pic.
I tried to convert a pdfenter code here and getting the error. can any one help me what i made wrong here

The error I am getting

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:785:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:797:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at ReadStream.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at ReadStream.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:519:10)
    at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:1001:34) {
  errno: -4047,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}


const { fromBase64, fromPath } = require("pdf2pic");
const { mkdirsSync, readFileSync } = require("fs-extra");
const rimraf = require("rimraf");

module.exports = () => {
  const specimen1 = "./files/specimen1.pdf";
  const outputDirectory = "./output";
  
  rimraf.sync(outputDirectory);
  mkdirsSync(outputDirectory);
  
  const options = {
    density: 100,
    saveFilename: "untitled",
    savePath: outputDirectory,
    format: "png",
    width: 600,
    height: 600
  };
  
  const storeAsImage = fromPath(specimen1, options);
  return storeAsImage(1).then( res=> { console.log(res)}).catch(error =>{ console.log(error)})
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while using Windows. You will need ImageMagick, which isn't automatically installed on later versions on GraphicsMagick. The solution was to download GraphicsMagick from the source code. See:
https://github.com/yakovmeister/pdf2image/blob/HEAD/docs/gm-installation.md
http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-windows.html